# mobx reaction is failing to trigger when adding to an observable array

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I'm attempting to trigger a mobx reaction when an item is added to or removed from an observable array.

Currently it's only triggered when removing an item

```js
type QueryParam = {
    name: string
    value: string
}

export default class SelectStore {
    rootStore: RootStore;
    constructor(rootStore: RootStore) {
        this.rootStore = rootStore;
    }

    @observable testRunFilters: QueryParam[] = [];

    @action updateTestRunFilter = (queryParam: QueryParam) => {
        const existingParam = this.testRunFilters.find(q => q.name === queryParam.name && q.value === queryParam.value);
        if (!existingParam) {
            this.testRunFilters.push(queryParam);
            //console.log('In updateTestRunFilter' + this.testRunFilters);
        }
    }

    @action removeTestRunFilter = (queryParamName: string) => {
        const existingParam = this.testRunFilters.find(q => q.name === queryParamName);
        if (existingParam) {
            this.testRunFilters = this.testRunFilters.filter(q => q.name !== queryParamName);
            //console.log('In removeTestRunFilter' + this.testRunFilters);
        }
    }

    myReaction = reaction(
        () => this.testRunFilters,
        (testRunFilters) => {
            console.log('Hello!' + testRunFilters);
        }
    );
}
```

The `console.log` in `updateTestRunFilter` is being triggered so I'm not sure what is wrong here?

I can't get it to work with a `Map` either, e.g. `@observable testRunFiltersMap = new Map();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `reaction` is wrong. The way it is now, it will only be triggered when you completely change the array ( new reference ). In order to trigger the reaction, you need to `watch` for the `length` property of the array. However, now the parameter that will be passed to the side effect will be just the array length.

```js
   myReaction = reaction(
        () => this.testRunFilters.length,
        (thisIsLengthNow) => {
            console.log('Hello!' + testRunFilters);
        }
    );
```

But you can always return more stuff from the `reaction` or just access the array with `this.testRunFilters` in side effect.